# SQL Query taking a long time to run

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I am trying to run this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
        a.ticketnumber 
    FROM 
        ticket_updates a 
    LEFT JOIN 
        ticket_updates b 
    ON 
        b.ticketnumber = a.sequence AND b.type = 'reminder_complete' 
    WHERE 
        b.ticketnumber IS NULL AND 
        (a.type = 'reminder' OR a.type = 'reminder_high') AND 
        (a.for_agent = '' OR a.for_agent = '2') AND 
        a.notes <= '2018-05-10 23:00:00' AND 
        a.ticketnumber NOT IN (
    SELECT ticketnumber 
                                FROM ticket_updates 
                                WHERE 
                                type = 'reminder_complete' AND 
                                ticketnumber = a.ticketnumber)
```

But for some reason, its taking 14.8126 seconds to return any results.

When testing, its returning 1 row and i cannot work out why its so slow. I believe its probably something to do with the joins but im hoping someone can help and point me in the right direction please?

I apologise if i have missed out any info, so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Have you added any indexes to your table?

Comment: How many ticket_updates do you have?

Comment: @JakubJudas 54419 records - but thats throughout the whole table

Comment: @charlie What about the individual subselect? How long does only that one take? What about the main query without the last NOT IN?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: the main query takes 0.9 seconds without the NOT IN

Comment: @charlie Try to adjust your innodb_buffer_pool_size - it sometimes does wonders and 54419 records with a join could be enough to fill the default buffer pool size (which is something ridiculously low like 128MB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the other Answers, you need these indexes:

```
a:  (type, for_agent, notes, ticket_number)
a:  (for_agent, type, notes, ticket_number)
ticket_updates:  (type, ticket_number)
```

It *might* help to combine the `LEFT JOIN` and the `NOT IN`:

```
AND NOT EXISTS 
   ( SELECT 1 
       FROM ticket_updates b
      WHERE b.ticketnumber IN ( a.sequence, a.ticketnumber )
        AND b.type = 'reminder_complete' )
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan.

The query is already using an anti-join pattern for `b`.

I recommend using the same anti-join pattern in place of the `NOT IN` check. (The big hump with anti-join seems to be getting our brain wrapped around it; once we understand the pattern, we should be able to make use of it.

Something like this:

```
SELECT a.ticketnumber
  FROM ticket_updates a
    -- anti-join
  LEFT
  JOIN ticket_updates b
    ON b.ticketnumber = a.sequence
   AND b.type         = 'reminder_complete'
    -- anti-join
  LEFT
  JOIN ticket_updates c
    ON c.ticketnumber = a.ticketnumber
   AND c.type         = 'reminder_complete'
    --
 WHERE c.ticketnumber IS NULL
   AND b.ticketnumber IS NULL
    --
   AND a.type      IN ('reminder','reminder_high')
   AND a.for_agent IN ('','2')
   AND a.notes     <= '2018-05-10 23:00:00'
```

As far as performance, we need to ensure suitable indexes are available.

Considering that the `NOT IN (correlated subquery)` is contributing to the execution time, replacing that with the anti-join makes it more likely that MySQL will make use of a suitable index if one is available. (In terms of performance, those repeated executions of a correlated subquery will eat our lunch, and our lunchbox too, if we're not careful.)

Again, use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan.

---

The anti-join pattern could be replaced with a `NOT EXISTS` to get an equivalent plan. (Counter intuitively, the anti-join pattern will sometimes show "not exists" in the Extra column of the EXPLAIN output, where a NOT EXISTS doesn't.)

I expect this will give an execution plan that is nearly equivalent:

```
SELECT a.ticketnumber
  FROM ticket_updates a
 WHERE a.type      IN ('reminder','reminder_high')
   AND a.for_agent IN ('','2')
   AND a.notes     <= '2018-05-10 23:00:00'

   AND NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1 
           FROM ticket_updates b
          WHERE b.ticketnumber = a.sequence
            AND b.type         = 'reminder_complete'
       )

   AND NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1 
           FROM ticket_updates c
          WHERE c.ticketnumber = a.ticketnumber
            AND c.type         = 'reminder_complete'
       )
```